# Parsing json enconded object containing html entities in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

I had a php object..that I converted to json text using **json_encode()** 
function. Then I passed it on **$.parseJSON()** function on javascript.

Note:The description field in json object contains text encoded in html entities..

On execution **$.parseJSON()** function says...

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal at
>   line 1 column 133 of the JSON data

However if description field just just had normal text like **"description":"hy"** there would be no problem in parsing **$.parseJSON()** function..

The need is I have to store description field with html entities that I have on database..

Help me out Guys...

```
$(window).load(function editPage(){
         var page_data = $.parseJSON('{"id":"1","title":"FAQ","summary":"Frequently Asked Questions are available here","description":"&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;\r\n&lt;html&gt;\r\n&lt;head&gt;\r\n&lt;\/head&gt;\r\n&lt;body&gt;\r\n&lt;h6 class=&quot;section-heading__heading heading--1&quot;&gt;What does Shopify do?&lt;\/h6&gt;\r\n&lt;p&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;\/p&gt;\r\n&lt;div class=&quot;grid-item grid-6 grid-push-1&quot;&gt;\r\n&lt;div class=&quot;long-form-content &quot;&gt;\r\n&lt;p&gt;Shopify is a complete &lt;code&gt;&lt;a class=&quot;body-link&quot; href=&quot;https:\/\/www.shopify.com\/&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot; rel=&quot;noopener&quot;&gt;ecommrce solution&lt;\/a&gt;&lt;\/code&gt; that allows you to set up an online store to sell your goods. It lets you organize your products, customize your storefront, accept credit card payments, track and respond to orders &amp;mdash; all with a few clicks of the mouse.&lt;\/p&gt;\r\n&lt;\/div&gt;\r\n&lt;\/div&gt;\r\n&lt;\/body&gt;\r\n&lt;\/html&gt;","status":"1","featured_image":"Page-1519912947103.jpg","added_date":"2018-03-01 19:46:28","updated_date":"2018-03-02 10:13:11"}');
               console.log(page_data);
               }
            );
```

Comment: hint `.replace(/\r\n/g, '')` - fixes it, but I don't know why! - actually I do, JSON shouldn't have `\r\n` in values

Comment: alternatively ... `.replace(/\r\n/g, '\\r\\n')` - so the description etc will now have the intended `\r\n`

Comment: Thank You so much Jaromanda for your help...as per you I replace all \r with \\r and all \n with \\n ...and it worked...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because JSON.parse cannot parse some special characters that are \n, \t, \r and \f.You need to replace it before parsing.

```
$(window).load(function editPage(){
        var jsonString='{"id":"1","title":"FAQ","summary":"Frequently Asked Questions are available here","description":"&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;\r\n&lt;html&gt;\r\n&lt;head&gt;\r\n&lt;\/head&gt;\r\n&lt;body&gt;\r\n&lt;h6 class=&quot;section-heading__heading heading--1&quot;&gt;What does Shopify do?&lt;\/h6&gt;\r\n&lt;p&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;\/p&gt;\r\n&lt;div class=&quot;grid-item grid-6 grid-push-1&quot;&gt;\r\n&lt;div class=&quot;long-form-content &quot;&gt;\r\n&lt;p&gt;Shopify is a complete &lt;code&gt;&lt;a class=&quot;body-link&quot; href=&quot;https:\/\/www.shopify.com\/&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot; rel=&quot;noopener&quot;&gt;ecommrce solution&lt;\/a&gt;&lt;\/code&gt; that allows you to set up an online store to sell your goods. It lets you organize your products, customize your storefront, accept credit card payments, track and respond to orders &amp;mdash; all with a few clicks of the mouse.&lt;\/p&gt;\r\n&lt;\/div&gt;\r\n&lt;\/div&gt;\r\n&lt;\/body&gt;\r\n&lt;\/html&gt;","status":"1","featured_image":"Page-1519912947103.jpg","added_date":"2018-03-01 19:46:28","updated_date":"2018-03-02 10:13:11"}';
        jsonString=jsonString.replace(/\n/g, "\\n")
            .replace(/\r/g, "\\r")
            .replace(/\t/g, "\\t")
            .replace(/\f/g, "\\f");
             var page_data = $.parseJSON(jsonString);
                   console.log(page_data);
                   }
                );
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help...I used your code..Its great but it worked only when i changed your .replace('\n', "\\n").replace('\r', "\\r").replace('\t', "\\t").replace('\f', "\\f") function to .replace(/\r\n/g, '\\r\\n')

Comment: @Ahsit Tamang When I was tried with '/\r\n/g 'from browser console, I got some error. That's why i changed the character. I don't know how its work in php. If i edit it, can you mark it as answer?

Comment: please change .replacee() as .replace() in your code ..spelling mistake

Answer (score 0):

After various suggestion by helpful hands ..my now working code is..

```
<script>
         $(window).load(function editPage(){

          var jsonString= '{"id":"1","title":"FAQ","summary":"Frequently Asked Questions are available here","description":"&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;\r\n&lt;html&gt;\r\n&lt;head&gt;\r\n&lt;\/head&gt;\r\n&lt;body&gt;\r\n&lt;h6 class=&quot;section-heading__heading heading--1&quot;&gt;What does Shopify do?&lt;\/h6&gt;\r\n&lt;p&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;\/p&gt;\r\n&lt;div class=&quot;grid-item grid-6 grid-push-1&quot;&gt;\r\n&lt;div class=&quot;long-form-content &quot;&gt;\r\n&lt;p&gt;Shopify is a complete &lt;code&gt;&lt;a class=&quot;body-link&quot; href=&quot;https:\/\/www.shopify.com\/&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot; rel=&quot;noopener&quot;&gt;ecommrce solution&lt;\/a&gt;&lt;\/code&gt; that allows you to set up an online store to sell your goods. It lets you organize your products, customize your storefront, accept credit card payments, track and respond to orders &amp;mdash; all with a few clicks of the mouse.&lt;\/p&gt;\r\n&lt;\/div&gt;\r\n&lt;\/div&gt;\r\n&lt;\/body&gt;\r\n&lt;\/html&gt;","status":"1","featured_image":"Page-1519912947103.jpg","added_date":"2018-03-01 19:46:28","updated_date":"2018-03-02 10:13:11"}';
          jsonString=jsonString.replace(/\r\n/g, '\\r\\n');
          var page_data =$.parseJSON(jsonString);
          console.log(page_data);
           }
        );
       </script>
```